# jquery tools overlay problem/conflict

Tags: jquery, overlay, jquery-tools

I am trying to combine jQuery Tools overlay with some simple code, though overlay won't work.

I have couple of div containers, like below. I go through with each function and add "right-margin: 0" and clearing break to every third item.

```
<div class="essay-thumb">
 <a href="link.html"><img src="src.jpg" alt="Alt text" width="210" height="140" /></a>
 <h5>Header Text h5</h5>
</div>
<div class="essay-thumb">
 <a href="link2.html"><img src="src2.jpg" alt="Alt text 2" width="210" height="140" /></a>
 <h5>Header Text h5 2</h5>
</div>
...
```

```
$('.essay-thumb').each(function(i){
 if ( ((i+1)%3) == 0 ) {
  $(this).css('margin-right', 0).after('<br class="clear" />');
 }
})
```

Here I add the rel attribute, grab the content of the alt attribute in img and add it to related div container in <span class="tooltip"><p>...</p></span> tag, set opacity via css to 0.

```
$('#content .essay-thumb').each(function(i){
 $(this).find('a').attr('rel', '#modal'+(i+1) );
 var title = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
 var link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
 $('<span class="tooltip"><\/span>').appendTo($(this))
 $('<p><\/p>').text(title).appendTo($(this).find('.tooltip'));
})
```

Then I animate the opacity to 0.8 on hover and back to 0

```
$('#content .essay-thumb').hover(function(e) {
  $(this).find('.tooltip').stop().animate({opacity: .8}, 500);
 }, function () { 
  $(this).find('.tooltip').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 200);
 })
```

Finally I have the line to trigger the overlay on click. This doesn't work though, I am wondering why? As far as i can see, the overlay event is not attached to related a tag. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
$("#content .essay-thumb a[rel]").overlay({ expose: '#000', effect: 'apple' });
```

Comment: In your .each you have `.attr('rel', '#modal'+(i+1) )`. Do you have the #modal elements in the DOM? The overlay will fail if the element referenced by the `rel` attribute does not exist.

Comment: You are right, I added these with this line, now it works: $('<div id="modal'+(i+1)+'" class="overlay-photoessay"><iframe src="' + link + '" width="850" height="522" frameborder="0"><\/iframe><\/div>').appendTo('body');